# Hash Value in RemotePayLoad

Tags: hash, wix, wix3, wix3.6, wix3.7

I am new to wix,can anyone please tell me how to work with hash value in remotePayload in wix.

```
 <RemotePayload
      Hash="D40DB6440BD2B5B5AA00DA63F408469FF22A9542"
      ProductName="vstor_redist.exe"
       Description="Dotnet 4.0"
       Size="39130"
       Version="4.0.5022.0" />
```

Inside an EXEPACKAGE i have used it.
But when the installer runs,it shows  **The Hash Value is incorrect**

Answer (score 6):

Where did you get this hashvalue?

simply use this to avoid any inconvinence.

```
<ExePackage 
              Id="InstallJava"
              DetectCondition='NOT Installed AND JAVACURRENTVERSION>="1.6"'
              InstallCondition='NOT VersionNT64'
              SourceFile="..\dep\jre-7u55-windows-i586.exe"  
              InstallCommand='/s'
              Compressed="no"
              Permanent="yes"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Vital="no"
              DownloadUrl="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=86895"
              />
```

Download the vstor_redist.exe and use SourceFile attribute to refer it. wix will automatically calculate the Hashcode, etc.

But if you are more inclined toward using RemotePayLoad then use heat.exe to harvest this data.

```
<wix-folder>/bin/heat payload d:\vstor_redist.exe -out d:\remote.xml
```

Comment: while using like this , the source file (..\dep\jre-7u55-windows-i586.exe ) will be also get added with the final setup na? I just want to auto download the Prerequisites from the web directly,during the installation. is it possible.?

Comment: You can try this. It will not package the prereq to your installer. Since I used **Compressed="no"**.